# Z-index problem with dropdown menu and elements with display hidden

Tags: css, z-index

I just added [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) to [my page](http://widerdesign.com.tw/). But the drop down menu displays under **my header-bottom div which has display: hidden.** But that's not the only problem it is also
covered by my [Easy Slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding) which has images and divs and I can't tell which one is covering my drop down menu.

I'm not very familiar using z-index
What's the best way of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Check that container, which contains your menu has relative position. Z-index works only for elements, which has position attribute 'relative' of 'absolute'.

For example:

```
<div style="position:relative">Menu here</div>
```

Comment: I made a wrapper div for my whole page set it relative and set my drop down menu absolute. I can't believe I did that just for a menu is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index property on both elements through CSS. (menu) and (slider)

```
<div style="z-index:2;">Menu</div>

<div style="z-index:1;">Slider (or whatever coming after the menu)</div>
```

and yes, the reason is using two elements with the `position:relative;`